# Prism EventAggregator - GetEvent by type

Tags: c#, generics, prism, eventaggregator

I would like to use

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent(typeof(SomeDomainEvent)).Subscribe();
```

instead of

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeDomainEvent>().Subscribe();
```

But GetEvent is not overloaded for that. How can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use reflection.

```
// Equivalent to:
//
// SomeDomainEvent eventObject = eventAggregator.GetEvent<SomeDomainEvent>();
MethodInfo getEventMethod = typeof(IEventAggregator).GetMethod("GetEvent");
MethodInfo genericGetEventMethod = getEventMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeDomainEvent));
object eventObject = genericGetEventMethod.Invoke(eventAggregator, null);

// Now choose the version of "Subscribe" you want to call
// Equivalent to:
// 
// eventObject.Subscribe(MyEventHandler);
Type[] subscribeTypes = new Type[] { typeof(Action<SomeDomainEventArgs>) });
MethodInfo subscribeMethod = eventObject.GetType().GetMethod("Subscribe", subscribeTypes);
subscribeMethod.Invoke(eventObject, new object[] { new Action<SomeDomainEventArgs>(MyEventHandler) });
```